# Create a read stream for a pdf file to upload to s3 bucket

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, stream, fs

I have an express service that's taking a pdf file from my front-end and saving it to an s3 bucket. I'm running into issues trying to take the file and create a stream so that I can then pass that to the s3 upload function. I'm trying to avoid writing the file to disc so I don't think I can use `fs.createReadStream()` but I can't seem to find an alternative way to do it..

```
router.post('/upload', upload.single('my-pdf'), async (req, res, next) {
   const file = req.file;
   
   // Needs a file path not an actual file
   const stream = fs.createReadStream(file);

   return s3.upload(file).promise();
}
```

Any help or advice on how to get around this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `req.file.<name_of_upload_field>` is a buffer holding the file contents, you can convert that to a readable stream via

```js
var str = new stream.PassThrough();
str.end(req.file.<name_of_upload_field>);
return s3.upload(str).promise();
```